# Authorization Error while hitting Endpoint via Proxy Service

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2, I have created a proxy service that hit a URL embedded in endpoint via POST method, for hitting that URL I require 3 header via POSTMAN, so I have embedded those headers inside the header mediator in WSO2 ESB. It does not require any Authorization when hitting via POSTMAN (Authorization section of POSTMAN has 'No Auth' in it).

When I am running my proxy service it is giving me "org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 401 Error: Unauthorized" error.

Below is my code:-

```
 <proxy name="SampleProxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
<target>
    <inSequence>
        <class description="classname" name="com.rocky.myclass"/>
        <log description="Log" level="custom">
            <property expression="get-property('sampleProperty')" name="Property_From_class"/>
        </log>
        <header name="Authorization" scope="transport" value="get-property('sampleProperty')"/>
        <header name="Host" scope="transport" value="hostname"/>
        <header name="Content-Type" scope="transport" value="text/plain"/>
        <send>
            <endpoint key="MyEP"/>
        </send>
    </inSequence>
    <outSequence>
        <respond/>
    </outSequence>
    <faultSequence/>
</target>
```

Any help how to resolve?

Comment: can you provide the reason of using class mediator? and can you confirm whether it's logging after class mediator or not.Are you getting the sample property from Class Mediator?Can you mention the endpoint point as well, like what kind of endpoint you are using.

Comment: Well i am able to solve it. No issues -)

Comment: Good, But next time be more descriptive with your questions as there were lots of things missing in your question.